# How can I change the working directory of MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe?

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

We are currently calling the runner like this:

```
D:\BuildTools\MSBSonarQubeRunner-1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:"someKey" /n:"someName" /v:"someVersion" /d:sonar.resharper.cs.reportPath="K:\somePath\resharper.xml"
```

We want to have the output of sonar in K:\.sonarqube

We tried to use the command line arg `/d:sonar.working.directory=K:\\.sonarqube`  but that didn't work. We also tried setting the working directory in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml like this: `<Property Name="sonar.working.directory">K:\.sonarqube\</Property>`

That didn't work too ...
We need to have it in a top directory, because the sonar runner throws an PathTooLongException (out path is 286 characters long).

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the working directory of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.

You can however launch the build from another folder, but all 3 steps (`begin`, `msbuild` and `end`) must be launched from that folder:

1. k:
2. D:\BuildTools\MSBSonarQubeRunner-1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin ....
3. msbuild /t:rebuild c:\whereever\your\sources\are\Solution.sln
4. D:\BuildTools\MSBSonarQubeRunner-1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end

Comment: We tried that but that did not work completely. The .sonarqube directory is now located under k:\ .sonarqube. So far it works like it was intended. But the D:\BuildTools\MSBSonarQubeRunner-1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end crashes. We don't really have a crash report, it only states that java wasn't used correctly.
We call the end through a batch file like this located directly under k:\sonar.bat  
    Set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\
D:\BuildTools\MSBSonarQubeRunner-1.0.2\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end > D:\ModuleBuild\Workspace\sonar.out 2> D:\ModuleBuild\Workspace\sonar.err

Comment: I won't be able to easily reproduce this - but definitely the `end` step shouldn't crash in this case. If you're able to tell me more about the crash, I'll create an issue on the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild project side

Comment: We solved the issue, your solution worked properly. Our issue was that we have Java 1.5 on the build server and didn't set the java_home to java 1.8 correctly